# Error message when installing scipy with pip install

Tags: python, scipy, pip

I am attempting to use pip install to install the scipy library through the command prompt.

When I type:

```
pip install scipy
```

I get a wall of white text, ending with a section of red text, shown below.

```
Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\us
ers\\stuart\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-edorla\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(compi
le(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __fil
e__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\stuart\appdata\local\temp\pip-vegpqd-re
cord\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed wi
th error code 1 in c:\users\stuart\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-edorla\scipy
```

I have tried searching for a fix, and followed instructions to upgrage to the latest version of setuptools which I have done using the

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

However when trying to install again I get the same error.

I am able to install numerous other libraries using pip install so it seems to be specific to scipy.

Would anyone have an idea why the installation may be failing?

Comment: What are the requirements for installing scipy on windows?

Comment: Thanks for the hint - after doing a quick search it seems that a fortran compiler may be needed to install scipy through pip - I used the .exe installer from sourceforge and it went through fine. Cheers :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a fortran compiler may be needed to install scipy through pip - I used the .exe installer from sourceforge and it went through fine.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.11.0/